# Jquery animation loads only when window size is minimised (Fiddle updated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello People I found a strange problem.

initial css of div 'floors'

```
.floors { 
height: 195.28px; 
width:241.89px;
margin-top: 30%;
}
```

Html Content:
    `<div id="map" class="floors" ></div>`

Jquery animate

```
$(".somediv").click(function(){
 $( ".main_floors" ).animate({
        width: "+=600px",
        height:'+=400px',
        marginLeft: "30%",
        fontSize: "3em",
      }, 1500 );
```

})

as shown above,initially I am loading `leaflet map` in a small window `floor` ,after a click of a button `floor` size increases ...then again map should load inside a big sized window(floor) ... its working fine...but the problem is after jquery animate i have to `change screen size manually by dragging browser window width or height` only then map will load completly else map will load only as in small winodw size (initla size window size) how to fix this?It could not any issues from map bcos i had same problem while loading static image,is there a way to refresh div(floor) after animate function?

Fiddle exactly same issue ...please check

https://jsfiddle.net/dh2p91o5/4/

Thanks @Rvervuurt for an updated image, yes that's the exact problem I am facing...

[Exact Issue as shown in pic](http://i.imgur.com/yDATrcc.gifv)

Comment: can you replicate the same with fiddle?

Comment: loading map data dynamically...tough to put it in fiddle...

Comment: Try anyway, maybe with non-dynamically loaded map data. It's difficult to find out why it doesn't work without a Fiddle.

Comment: @Rvervuurt  please check fiddle ... same problem....  https://jsfiddle.net/dh2p91o5/4/

Comment: @GuruprasadRao fiddle updated...

Comment: So I'm guessing you mean the grey area, that it doesn't get filled up automatically? http://i.imgur.com/yDATrcc.gifv (feel free to add it to the question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, what you are looking for?

```
$( "#run").click(function() {

  $( "#map" ).animate({
            width: "+=300px",
            height:'+=300px',
            marginLeft: "30%",
            position: "absolute",
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    complete: function() {
        map._onResize(); 

    }
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dh2p91o5/9/

I know, it "jumps" a little, but at least it is working or a point to investigate furthermore ...

Please try and tell me, if this is what you wanted to achive.

Comment: Thanks alot ...Its much better .I think its enough for me. ;)You deserve +1 for sure ;)